# Post using modRestController Class at MODX

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I am developing a modx RESTful API. I would like to ask, if anyone knows how to post directly from browser to modRestController class and finally with this post I can save the information to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this two posts will help you:

1. [You need to create](https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extending-modx/developing-restful-api) proper REST API files&folders structure
2. Implement [custom database](https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extending-modx/tutorials/using-custom-database-tables) logic
3. Call 2 in 1

Comment: Hi Anton, I created the REST API and Xml schema, and if I make a GET request from the browser, the table content appears. But in this specific case, I am trying to do a POST request to save the information directly to DB [MyController][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXvxG.png

Comment: method modRestServiceRequest() basically works with global $_SERVER[‘REQUEST_METHOD’] variable, please check what is inside: var_dump($_SERVER[‘REQUEST_METHOD’])

Comment: I am also learning to create my first REST API on MODX3. The links that @AntonTarasov provided were really useful. Also, this video helped me a lot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6gFjBkop68. I am still wondering, what could be the easiest way to implement object-level access rights so that a user could GET only his own objects (the SQL table would have a field telling the owner). And what is the way to implement custom parameters: for example to fetch only objects that have "active" field set to true.